# Unable to send date to the date field with SendKeys in Firefox browser(version 65) using Protractor

Tags: javascript, datepicker, protractor

Unable to send date to the date field with sendkeys. As soon as the mouse control goes to the date field calendar pop-up(Cannot inspect Calendar) and sendKeys doesn't enter date in the date field. It is working fine in Chrome browser as calendar in chrome browser doesn't pop-up when control is moved to date field

1. Tried click action on the date field first and then sent date using sendKeys

{datefield locator}.click();

{datefield locator}.sendKeys('04/08/2019');

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500284/firefox-cannot-sendkeys-to-date-picker), it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try javascript executor like below

```
// find the element and set value
browser.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('//your locator class name')[0].value='text to set'");
```

Comment: Using above line of code, test case has passed but did not set the date to the date field.

Comment: @seleniumuser123 Try adding some wait until the page loads

Comment: can you share your implementation?

Comment: I have requested Dev's to add date picker to the date field which would solve the problem. thanks for responding.